# Python dictionaries and formatting

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to solve the same a problem that does the following...
Create a program that stores Employee objects in a dictionary. Use the employee ID number as the key. The program should present a menu that lets the user perform the following actions:

- Look up an employee in the dictionary
- Add a new employee to the dictionary
- Change an existing employee’s name, department, and job title in the
  dictionary
- Delete an employee from the dictionary
- Quit the program

When the program ends, it should pickle the dictionary and save it to a file. Each time the program starts, it should try to load the pickled dictionary from the file. If the file does not exist, the program should start with an empty dictionary.

I found another user that posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39606186/4035833) but I am having some different problems.

1. How should I quit the program? I tried break but it failed
   miserably.
2. I know my formatting is atrocious but I can't figure out where it is
   going wrong.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    if os.path.exists("employee.dat"):
        file = open("employee.dat","rb")
        employee_dictionary = pickle.load(file)
        file.close()

    else:
        emp1 = Employee("Susan Myers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President")
        emp2 = Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer")
        emp3 = Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer")

        employee_dictionary = {emp1.get_ID_number(): emp1.get_name()+ '' + emp1.get_dept()+ '' + emp1.get_job_title(),\
                               emp2.get_ID_number(): emp2.get_name()+ '' + emp2.get_dept()+ '' + emp2.get_job_title(),\
                               emp3.get_ID_number(): emp3.get_name()+ '' + emp3.get_dept()+ '' + emp3.get_job_title()}

#should I add another function here to call the employee_dictionary?
choice = 'y'
while choice.upper()== 'Y':
    print("Make a selection from the following actions:")
    print("Lookup an employee in the dictionary: 1")
    print("Add a new employee to the dictionary: 2")
    print("Change an existing employee's name, department, and job title in the dictionary: 3")
    print("Delete an employee from the dictionary: 4")
    print("Quit the program: 5")
    selection = input("Make your selection: ")

    if int(selection) == 1:
        id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

        if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
            print(employee_dictionary[int(id_number)])

        else:
            print("The employee does not exist.")

    else:
        if int(selection) == 2:
            id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

            if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
                print('That employee already exists.')

            else:
                name = input("Enter the name of the employee:")
                dept = input("Enter the department of the employee:")
                title = input("Enter the job title of the employee:")
                emp4 = Employee(name,int(id_number), dept, title)
                employee_dictionary[emp4.get_ID_number()]= emp1.get_name()+ '' + emp4.get_dept()+ '' + emp4.get_job_title()

                print("The employee was added.")

        else:
            if int(selection) == 3:
                id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

                if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
                    name = input("Enter the name of the employee:")
                    dept = input("Enter the department of the employee:")
                    title = input("Enter the job title of the employee:")
                    emp4 = Employee(name,int(id_number), dept, title)
                    employee_dictionary[emp4.get_ID_number()]= emp1.get_name()+ '' + emp4.get_dept()+ '' + emp4.get_job_title()

                    print("The employee record has been updated.")

                else:
                    print("Record not found.")

            else:
                if int(selection) == 4:
                    id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")
                    print("Deleted: ", employee_dictionary.pop(int(id_number),"Record not found."))

                else:
                    if int(selection)!=5:
                        print("")

    #break

choice = input("Do you want to make another selection (y or n)?")
file = open('employee.dat','wb')
pickle.dump(employee_dictionary,file)
file.close()

main()
```

Comment: it's skipping because you aren't calling the main function until after asking for inputs. I'd recommend looking at your structure and putting some lines in to test what variables look like at certain points so you can understand what is going on when it runs. or if you are using an IDE put in some break points and view what the variables look like at certain intervals. Also there are a bunch of ways to quit the program but I am not that good on which one to use. But something like quit() probably will help. As for your emp2 i'd say have a go at populating it first and show the results.

Comment: I suppose you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) first. It answers a number of questions.

Comment: I fixed the dictionary and some of the formatting. When I corrected the formatting I found where one of the issues was with the while loop. Now I am getting an error saying that the  employee_dictionary is not defined. I know it is because it is being called outside of the function. Should I just create another function and call it there?